# Troubleshooting TFS 2013

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I have tfs installed locally on my machine. It used to work fine but for a week or so now, it does not work most of the time.

1. It is not possible to connect from Visual Studio 2013 now using the team menu item. It is able to connect only once in so many tries.
2. Git Fetch, Git Pull and Git Push commands from Git Bash take a long time to show the login prompts and sometimes does not even working reporting that it could not connect to localhost:8080
3. Fetch, Push and Pull from Visual Studio work once in a while.
4. Connecting with the web always works though sometimes slow.
5. Git Push with Git Bash and Gui of late gives the error below

   - POST git-receive-pack (8010 bytes)
   - fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
   - fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
   - error: RPC failed; result=7, HTTP code = 0
   - Pushing to `http://localhost:8080/tfs/col1/_git/project1`
   - Everything up-to-date

I've read so many articles and now seem to work. Is there a way to troubleshoot TFS to find out where it is coming from so that it can be corrected.

Comment: If they only work once in a while, what happens when they don't work?

Comment: Throws errors like localhost:8080 was not found, the remote end hung up, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out this had nothing to do with TFS as generally requests that have to do with local host fails most of the time. It may be an issue with the system when it comes to local host. In any case, I disabled IPv6 and it still didn't work.

What worked however was rawcap. I realized that when I run [rawCap](http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap) to monitor 127.0.0.1, all calls were going through successfully. It appears something it did rectified the issue. Hope it helps someone who also had the same issue with localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Watch for -1 statuses in TFS Activity Log (`http://localhost:8080/tfs/_oi`). Right click -> Show  Detail to get the full exception. Also look for errors in the [IIS logs](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/analyzing-client-usage-data-with-iis-user-access-logging).

[image: TFS Activity Log]

Comment: Hi @KMoraz, I observed that my issue apparently had nothing to do with TFS but some issue with local host on my machine. I'm however interested in this way of viewing the activities. I some some -1 but they were very few and only 1 was from my account and none was for today. That is good information. Thanks.